# How to use R, stringr or other package to replace a group of words from a long string?

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I am studying use R and stringr. Let's say I have a string:

```
a <- 'fda afe faref a about fae faef across afef absolute fgprg'
```

I have a data frame which includes some words that I want to remove from a:

```
b <- tibble(words=c('a','about','across'))
```

In my data, there are probably a lot of words in b. Here is just an example.

I want to remove all the words in b from a using R, stringr or other functions if there is better. I hope the result would be:

```
'fda afe faref fae faef afef absolute fgprg'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
gsub(paste0("\\b", paste0(b$words, collapse = "\\b( )?|\\b"), "\\b( )?"), "", a)
# [1] "fda afe faref fae faef afef absolute fgprg"
```

`\\b` indicates the word boundary and with `|` we match several possible words. `( )?` checks whether there is a space afterwards and removes that as well.

So we are matching the following expression in `gsub`:

```
paste0("\\b", paste0(b$words, collapse = "\\b( )?|\\b"), "\\b( )?")
# [1] "\\ba\\b( )?|\\babout\\b( )?|\\bacross\\b( )?"
```

Or with `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(a, str_c("\\b", str_c(b$words, collapse = "\\b( )?|"), "\\b( )?"), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gsub`, for the `a` we need to specify "word boundaries" by regex with `\b`.

```
gsub("\\ba \\b|about |across ", "", a)
# [1] "fda afe faref fae faef afef absolute fgprg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub` where `\\b` marks a word begin/end and `*` removes the white space if there is one.

```
gsub(paste0(" *\\b",b,"\\b *", collapse = "|"), "", a)
#[1] "fda afe faref fae faef afef absolute fgprg"
```

Data:

```
a <- 'fda afe faref a about fae faef across afef absolute fgprg'
b <- c('a','about','across')
```